# sql dw count(*) with selected columns doesn't aggregate

Tags: sql, group-by, count, azure-synapse

This is rather strange, and I have had this query work on numerous databases but here I am stumped.
I know that my Synapse table has duplicates

```
SELECT nmiandnmisuffixkey, ReadingDate, IntervalNumber
FROM [dbo].[factMeterDataDetail]
where nmiandnmisuffixkey = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
and readingdate = '2020-10-08'
and IntervalNumber = 12
```

produces

```
+--------------------+-------------+----------------+
| nmiandnmisuffixkey | ReadingDate | IntervalNumber |
+--------------------+-------------+----------------+
| XXXXXXXXXX         | 2020-10-08  |             12 |
| XXXXXXXXXX         | 2020-10-08  |             12 |
+--------------------+-------------+----------------+
```

but when I try to run following

```
SELECT nmiandnmisuffixkey, ReadingDate, IntervalNumber, count(*) as cnt
FROM [dbo].[factMeterDataDetail]
where nmiandnmisuffixkey = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
and readingdate = '2020-10-08'
and IntervalNumber = 12
group by nmiandnmisuffixkey, ReadingDate, IntervalNumber
```

I get the following:-

```
+--------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+
| nmiandnmisuffixkey | ReadingDate | IntervalNumber | cnt |
+--------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+
| XXXXXXXXXX         | 2020-10-08  |             12 |   1 |
| XXXXXXXXXX         | 2020-10-08  |             12 |   1 |
+--------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+
```

why does the count not aggregate up?

Comment: Some possibilities 1. date has different time/millisecond. so, you can try removing time part and run group by query again.. 2. string column(key) can have spaces. you can use `ltrim/rtrim` and run group by query again.

Comment: The column carrying dates is of `date` type and I tried `ltrim/rtrim` but they don't seem to have any effect. In short, there aren't any whitespaces trailing or leading whitespaces

Comment: did you try `upper(nmiandnmisuffixkey) `? if yes, then i am not sure there must be something different in them.

Comment: @BalajeeAddanki . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle illustrating this?

Comment: @KoushikRoy, you were right. The `ltrim\rtrim` actually worked. I ran the query again with `SELECT count(*) as [Cnt], rtrim(ltrim([NMIAndNMISuffixKey])),  [ReadingDate],  [IntervalNumber] FROM [dbo].[factMeterDataDetail] WHERE     rtrim(ltrim([NMIAndNMISuffixKey])) = 'XXXXXXXXXX' and [ReadingDate] = '2020-10-08'    and [IntervalNumber] = 12 group by rtrim(ltrim([NMIAndNMISuffixKey])), [ReadingDate], [IntervalNumber]` and it seemed to work fine. I am confused by this behavior though as the column is explicitly defined as `varchar(12)` and there are no values are varying length

Comment: @GordonLinoff  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/92xTfuP1m8oW3pc9yN6yVa/1#&togetherjs=S8AvtfAwbC

Comment: I am marking above comment as answer since it resolved this issue. Now, this can be an issue with the DB client tool as well. I used one tool called sqldbx which normally remove white space in where clause, in display. so, for that tool `where '  5' = '5'` will be true. So 'try to be smart' client tools can be difficult to handle.

Comment: I do have to mention that the three columns I have selected are actually primary keys of my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possibilities -

1. date has different time/millisecond. so, you can try removing time part and run group by query again.
2. string column(key) can have white spaces in the end or begining. you can use ltrim/rtrim and run group by query again. Client tool will display them as identical data like your output. By trimming space there can be a true comparison.

In OP's case, it was case #2. Using ltrim/rtrim resolved the agg issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
select nmiandnmisuffixkey, ReadingDate, IntervalNumber, count(*) as cnt
from [dbo].[factMeterDataDetail]
where nmiandnmisuffixkey = 'XXXXXXXXXX' and
      readingdate = '2020-10-08' and
      IntervalNumber = 12
group by nmiandnmisuffixkey, ReadingDate, IntervalNumber
```

The query is filtering on specific values for each of the columns used in the `group by`.  And yet, you are getting multiple rows when aggregating on them.

So, your question is really:  "When does an equality comparison not match the concept of "equality" for aggregation?"

I'm sure this is not a comprehensive list.

One possibility is that `IntervalNumber` is really a string.  The `=` converts the values to a number, so `'012'` and `'12'` are the same for equality, but not for aggregation.  ([Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dfba70f7c3f3e151a0c1b1e575aa75ae) is an example.)

In other words, type conversion can cause this discrepancy.

This might occur with strings and collations.  Normally, I would expect a collation conflict error.  But you might check if the string columns have an explicit collation different from the database default (which would be used for the string constant).

I don't think there is an equivalent difference for your date comparison.

I should also note a workaround for this use-case:

```
select max(nmiandnmisuffixkey), max(ReadingDate), max(IntervalNumber), count(*) as cnt
from [dbo].[factMeterDataDetail]
where nmiandnmisuffixkey = 'XXXXXXXXXX' and
      readingdate = '2020-10-08' and
      IntervalNumber = 12;
```

That is, just use an aggregation query with no `group by`.  It is guaranteed to return one row.

Comment: The table collation and the column collation are one and the same `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Answer (score 0):

Your table definitely has an ID. When you do count (*) it includes the ID. First, put the desired fields in a temp table, then group by.

In this way:

```
SELECT
    nmiandnmisuffixkey, ReadingDate, IntervalNumber
Into
    #tmp FROM [dbo].[factMeterDataDetail]
where
    nmiandnmisuffixkey = 'XXXXXXXXXX' and readingdate = '2020-10-08' and IntervalNumber = 12

Select
    nmiandnmisuffixkey, ReadingDate, IntervalNumber,count (*)as cnt
from
    #tmp 
Group by
    nmiandnmisuffixkey, ReadingDate, IntervalNumber
```